# Cloning a private Repo hangs for new 2.32.0.windows.1 version of git

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

**Question:**

Why does git-bash hang when cloning a non-public repo when installed with defaults?

**Context:**

I ran into this issue when trying to clone a private GitHub repo on my co-workers Windows 10 machine.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Installed the newest version of git bash for Windows (for at the time of writing this post for me was 2.32.0.windows.1). Choosing all of the defaults.
2. Run `git clone [http-link-to-private-repo]`

[image: Screenshot of hanging git clone command]

**Expected:**

1. A popup to enter username and password information.

**My Hack Solution:**

1. When installing 2.32.0. for windows check the "Enable experimental support for pseudo consoles.".

[image: Screenshot of hack option selection]

This allows the bash console to present you an option to authenticate via a web browser or a personal access token.

[image: Screenshot of work-around]

**Unrelated Note:**

I originally was looking to post this on the Github Issues page for Git but they don't have one so here I am. Not sure if this is the appropriate place to post this but I wanted it somewhere so another person doesn't run into the same trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks this was the solution after everything else failed including setting up a new installation, a new access token, and trying to find faulty config files.

After updating my personal access token this behavior also occurred with git 2.28.0.

So i did an update to the newest git version and afterwards the above mentioned steps.

(Sorry, i can not make any comments directly.)

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem setting up my dev environment for a new work laptop... Thankfully I had an older Windows GitBash installer (2.31.1) so I ended up downgrading to the older version. Worked like a charm, for me but understand it may not be an option for everyone.